# Can I convert arbitrary audio to FLAC with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, audio, encoding

I want to convert any audio (mp3, wav, etc) to FLAC with pure JS as I can't use any third party tools. Is this possible? Ideally, I'd like to pipe it.

Comment: "Any audio"? That's a very, very wide mandate. "I can't use any third party tools"... that's going to sink this project. You'll need a whole suite of decoders and at least one encoder. I don't see how this differs from a product recommendation request (for 3rd party tools), and this question is also too broad by a seriously wide margin. I voted to close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With pureJS, probably no. You'd need to at the least include some bindings for a C++ nodejs extension for encoding/decoding (like lameMP3).

You could create the bindings yourself if you're up for it using [N-API](https://nodejs.org/api/n-api.html)

---

You could, of course, go the absolutely insane route and read the files into memory, convert the stream to a UInt32Array (or something), figure out how it's encoded, then convert it yourself with some algo.